# Is お引っ越しします a humble form used only in the title?

Tags: keigo

I searched the Internet and found that people use お引っ越しします in the title/headline, but when it comes to the body, they omit the お.
Here is the posts I saw:

1. the title of [this post](https://ameblo.jp/cute2010/entry-12765490280.html) is お引越ししました～(^^)/. In the body the op uses 無事に新しいおうちに**引っ越ししました** (We have safely moved into our new home.)
2. the title of [this post](https://hamusuta.blog-rpg.com/Entry/201/) is お引っ越しします. In the body the op uses 忍者ブログからライブドアブログに**引っ越しする**ことになりました。(We are moving from Ninja Blog to Livedoor Blog.)

I know お+verb stem+する is a humble form, to speak humbly of my own actions when they are related to someone I'm showing respect to.

I guess it's because in the headline they are informing their readers (who they need to respect) about the move, while in the body the OPs are just stating facts.

But why can't the body also be interpreted as informing the readers about the moving? is it right to say 無事に新しいおうちに**お**引っ越ししました or ライブドアブログに**お**引っ越しすることになりました here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This お引っ越し is a [美化語 (beatified word)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/86216/5010) of 引っ越し, and it can be safely used to refer to things belonging to the speaker. お引っ越ししました is not a humble expression (nor an honorific expression) but just plain "did (お)引っ越し".

There is essentially no difference between お引っ越ししました, 引っ越ししました and 引っ越しました. One may argue the first one is slightly politer than the other two, but the difference is almost negligible. People may use them randomly regardless of whether it's in a title or not. (But note that お引っ越しました is ungrammatical.)

Related: [Politeness of 何をお願いしましたか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77710/5010)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It shows me where I was getting trapped in my thinking. 引っ越し is a noun and 引っ越す is a verb. I got the two mixed up.  Thank you for telling me about 美化語!