# Why add お～ in おすすめ even when talking about YOUR own advice?

Tags: keigo, honorifics

I am basically checking my own understanding:

I remember from 敬語 basics in Minna that you say ご案内いたします, for example, with the honorific prefix, even though it's essentially you who are doing the action

Is it the same logic at work here, i.e. the honorific is used because you give advice for the sake of the listener?

P.S. Just in case, I first noticed it not so long ago [here](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/en/tv/easyjapaneseforwork/skit03.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terminology: Does the term 美化語 include all ご・お・etc. prefixes, or only ones outside of a 敬語 context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/86215/terminology-does-the-term-%e7%be%8e%e5%8c%96%e8%aa%9e-include-all-%e3%81%94-%e3%81%8a-etc-prefixes-or-only-ones-outsi) / [Politeness of 何をお願いしましたか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77710/5010) / [Is お引っ越しします a humble form used only in the title?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/96832/5010)

Comment: Thank you. It was informative. So, it seems that yes, as Manabさん also pointed out, お in おすすめ is just a part of the word in the modern usage

Answer (score 1):

Some words just get really associated with the honorific お。That is why you will rarely see お金 without the お.

ご案内致します uses the humble language 謙譲語, therefore you use it to talk about your own actions. "I will humbly guide you".

致す is the humble form of する

Comment: Ah, yes, I have never seen just すすめ for "advice". I see. Thank you!